# How can I distinguish between user-initiated and system initiated processes?

Tags: c#, .net, process

My code snippet is like this:-

```
KillUserProcess()  
{  
  foreach (Process myProcess in Process.GetProcesses())   
   {  
      // here I need to know which is system process and which is user process:  
       like --if(myProcess.type==user)  
               myProcess.Kill();  
}
```

actually i want to stop all user-initiated processes but not system-initiated processes.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do that? You'd kill your own process, explorer.exe, important processes some of which put an icon in the tray, and who knows what else.

Comment: How are you defining "system process?"  Something started by the system?  Aren't all processes started by the system in one way or another?

Comment: Here is a pretty straightforward way to determine the owner of the process with WMI:  http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.languages.csharp/browse_thread/thread/71ca5def3013974a/2a6272a9b7ecd77b?lnk=st&q=user+is+using+which+process+wmi+coad&rnum=1&pli=1

Comment: actually through my application i want to stop all user initiated process. just that....

Comment: @cdhowie:- when you open task manager ,it shows you which are user and which are system processes.

Comment: Start menu (explorer.exe) also runs in the account of the current user, you can't seriously want to kill that, too. On my laptop, most laptop utilities that handle power sawing and hotkeys also run in my account. If anyone wanted to kill them, I would kill them back :)

Comment: @Pranav: Where? Under "User Name?" That's the process owner. If by "system process" the OP meant "processes started by the SYSTEM user," then that's the definition I was looking for.

Comment: @Pranav: Like fejesjoco said, "explorer.exe" (among others) is listed as a "user" process in Task Manager. You'd be closing that, too, which is probably not a good idea.

Comment: What is a user initiated process? When I login, the shell is initated "on my command". Because I initiated the login. Is the shell also a user initiated process? What about the processes that are initiated when the user toggles the power state? What about the powsershell command: "restart-service mssqlserver". Does this switch the sql server process from system to user-initiated?

Comment: @fejesjoco:- ok i got you : actually i should say process owner than  user process...

Comment: @Brad:- thanks brad ..that was useful link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To kill most user initiated processes:

```
 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("shutdown -l");
```

Comment: Is it safe to rely on shutdown.exe?  Will it always be in the path?  Will all of the OSes running this program have it?

Comment: Oh. You actually wanted to *log off* the current user?

Comment: @Cody, If you kill all "user initiated processes", thats the result, isn't it?

Comment: I'm not critiquing your answer. I just never would have thought of it, reading the question. I'm more surprised that it was *accepted* rather than that you posted it.

Comment: @Cody: I'm rather surprised too.

Answer (score 2):

Found here on Bytes.com : [Get Process Account Name](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/248534-get-account-name-associated-running-process).

You can use System.Management and the Win32_Process class.

```
using System;
using System.Management;
using System.Diagnostics;
class App {
    public static void Main() {
    GetProcessInfo(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle. ToInt32());
    }

    static void GetProcessInfo(int handle)
    {
        using(ManagementObject proc = new ManagementObject("Win32_Process.Handle='" + handle.ToString() + "'"))
        {
            proc.Get();
            string[] s = new String[2];
            //Invoke the method and populate the array with the user name and domain
            proc.InvokeMethod("GetOwner",(object[])s);
            Console.WriteLine("User: " + s[1]+ "\\" + s[0]);
        }
    }
}
```